# Merge overlapping sessions, how do I find the end value of the session? [Leetcode Similar to Car Pooling]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following code block which figures out the number of overlapping sessions. Given different intervals, the task is to print the maximum number of overlap among these intervals at any time and also to find the overlapped interval.

```
def overlap(v): 

    # variable to store the maximum 
    # count 
    ans = 0
    count = 0
    data = [] 

    # storing the x and y 
    # coordinates in data vector 
    for i in range(len(v)): 

        # pushing the x coordinate 
        data.append([v[i][0], 'x']) 

        # pushing the y coordinate 
        data.append([v[i][1], 'y']) 

    # sorting of ranges 
    data = sorted(data) 

    # Traverse the data vector to 
    # count number of overlaps 
    for i in range(len(data)): 

        # if x occur it means a new range 
        # is added so we increase count 
        if (data[i][1] == 'x'): 
            count += 1

        # if y occur it means a range 
        # is ended so we decrease count 
        if (data[i][1] == 'y'): 
            count -= 1

        # updating the value of ans 
        # after every traversal 
        ans = max(ans, count) 

    # printing the maximum value 
    print(ans) 

# Driver code 
v = [[ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 6 ],[3,8]] 
overlap(v)
```

This returns `3`.
But what would be the best way to also return the maximum overlapping interval by modifying my existing approach? In this case which should be `[3,4]`.

Comment: @martineau any suggestions for the problem ?

Comment: Hey, i think you can check for the value in `v`. Looping, then check the first element. `for x in v: if i[0] == ans: final =  i`. `final` as the result, then print it.

Comment: Nothing specific, but it might be worthwhile to define your own `Interval` class that has methods to determine its relationship to another instance of the class — like whether it intersects, overlaps, or is completely disjoint from it. This seems like it would make the logic for determining what you want much easier. See this [Interval FAQ](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~georgec/IFAQ/huang1.html) for a better explanation.

Comment: @IlyaTrianggela That doesnt seem to work. How do I get the end value 4 in that case? I expect the return value to be `[3,4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the counter object (from collections) to create a list of intersecting sub intervals and count the number of original intervals that intersect with them. Each interval in your list would be intersected with all the sub-intervals found so far in order to accumulate the counts:

```
v = [[ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 6 ],[3,8]] 

from collections import Counter
overCounts = Counter()
for vStart,vEnd in v:
    overlaps = [(max(s,vStart),min(e,vEnd)) for s,e in overCounts 
                if s<=vEnd and e>=vStart]
    overCounts += Counter(overlaps + [(vStart,vEnd)])

interval,count = overCounts.most_common(1)[0]
print(interval,count) # (3,4) 3
```

The overlaps list detects intersections with the sub-intervals found so far.  `s<=vEnd and e>=vStart` will return True when interval (s,e) intersects with interval (vStart,vEnd).  For those intervals that do intersect we want the start and end of the intersection (sub-interval).  The intersection will start at the largest beginning and end at the smallest end.  So we take the max() of the start positions with the min() of the end positions to form the sub-interval: `(max(s,vStart),min(e,vEnd))`

```
vStart               vEnd
[--------------------]
       [--------------------------]
       s                          e

       [-------------]
--max->               <----min-----
```

**[EDIT]** 
To be honest, I like your original approach better than mine.  It will respond in O(NLogN) time whereas mine could go up to O(N^2) depending on the data.

In order to capture the sub-interval corresponding to the result in your original approach, you would need to add a variable to keep track of the last starting position encountered and move detection of a higher count inside the 'y' condition.

For example:

```
 lastStart = maxStart = maxEnd = None

 # ...

    if (data[i][1] == 'x'): 
        lastStart = data[i][0]     # last start of sub-interval 
        count += 1

    if (data[i][1] == 'y'): 
        if count > ans:            # detect a greater overlap
           maxStart = lastStart    # start of corresponding sub-interval
           maxEnd   = data[i][0]
           ans      = count 
        count -= 1

    # ans = max(ans, count)  <-- removed

# ...
```

You could also implement it using accumulate:

```
v = [[ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 6 ],[3,8]]

from itertools import accumulate
edges           = sorted((p,e) for i in v for p,e in zip(i,(-1,1)))
counts          = accumulate(-e for _,e in edges)
starts          = accumulate((p*(e<0) for p,e in edges),max)
count,start,end = max((c+1,s,p) for c,s,(p,e) in zip(counts,starts,edges) if e>0)

print(count,[start,end]) # 3 [3, 4]
```

Comment: Great solution, upvoted it. Can you please perhaps break this line down and help explain:
```overlaps = [(max(s,vStart),min(e,vEnd)) for s,e in overCounts
                if s<=vEnd and e>=vStart]```
Also, what would be the time complexity of the solution? Would this be an ideal solution in an  interview setting?

Comment: Complexity should be between O(N) and O(N^2). Best case if all intervals are equal (N iterations). If there are no overlaps, there will be N*(N+1)/2 iterations over the overCounts items. In the worst case scenario, every interval will have a distinct intersection with every other which would produce N*(N+3)/2 intervals added over N iterations.

Comment: @AlainT. Is there a way however to modify my existing solution to derive the desired output? It would be great to understand what I am missing in my original approach.

Comment: @AlainT. Couldn't help myself from commenting. Great explanation on all the approaches.